# Outlook VSTO how to identify Sharepoint task?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, outlook, outlook-addin

I am creating Outlook 2013/16 Add-in that will display additional information for tasks synced from Sharepoint. I can identify that task is from Sharepoint folder and get name of the folder.

But I cannot identify particular task for requesting data from Sharepoint. Sharepoint tasks contains identificators `ID, UniqueID` and `GUID`. But none of these can be accessed in `Outlook.TaskItem` object. This object contains `EntryID` property but its Guid is different from those on the Sharepoint task object.

Is there any way I can find out what particular Sharepoint task is opened in Outlook?

Comment: Check if you can see anything SharePoint specific on the MAPI level - take a look at the task with OutlookSpy (click IMessage),. You can access any MAPI property using TaskItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [PropertyAccessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff869735.aspx) object to read the following properties in the TaskItem:

STS_Id (the list item ID; http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/STS_Id/0x00000003)

STS_ListGUID (the list ID; http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/STS_ListGUID/0x00000048)